# What happens if i name a field in a mysql table with "when"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a table with 3 columns
ID (Primary key), when (some varchar value), Created_date(timestamp)

**Will naming a field with "When" creates any issue?**

I have been querying like `update table set table.when='$when' where ID='1'`

Please suggest

Comment: Yes. Avoid naming your columns as keywords.

Comment: Ya sure, But actually i have a huge collection of web services, and so i have to alter them. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's **ok** as long as you have to use the tableName along with the column name

```
update `table` 
set `table`.when='$when' 
where ID='1'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75875/1)

otherwise, wrap it with backticks

```
update `table` 
set `when`='$when' 
where ID='1'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75875/3)

Other Link:

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

if possible don't use names or identifiers which are on the reserved keyword list to avoid problems.

Comment: if i make sure that i place a back ticks as 'when', code will not be effected right? By mistake i have added system reserved keyword. Thanks for your reply @JW

Comment: yes but be sure that you will use backticks and not singe quotes. `:D`